# VBA: Copy whole word document to excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, copy

I´m trying to simply copy whole word document into excel and keep the source formatting (and images).

Assuming both documents are open.
I tried this code:

```
Sheets("Nabídka").Range("A" & 87) = Documents("K4E pila.docx").Range.Text
```

but it only copies the text without formatting and images. Is there a similar command which includes the formatting?
Even If I copy/paste from word to excel (ctrl+c) the formatting is ruined --> The image overlaps the text.

This is the first step I need to figure out to proceed in my project. The outcome should be: Copy all word documents into excel if the name of the word document matches some excel cells values.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You can use worksheet.OLEObjects.Add(), where worksheet is whichever worksheet you want to add the document to.

Comment: Thank you. It was very helpfull.